# Dynamic list length leads to "IndexError: list index out of range" with pandas.DataFrame - how to best avoid?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I try to build a `pd.DataFrame` with dates stored in a list. Before the list is handed over to pandas it is appended or not depending on conditions, changing it's length. Example code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime

start_date = datetime.date(2025, 1, 1)

date_lst = [datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), datetime.date(2021, 1, 1)]
condition = 0


if date_lst[0] > start_date:
    date_lst.append(datetime.date(2022, 1, 1))
    date_lst.append(datetime.date(2023, 1, 1))
else:
    pass

df = pd.DataFrame([
        dict(Task="DateRange 1", Start=date_lst[0], End=date_lst[1]),
        dict(Task="DateRange 2", Start=date_lst[2], End=date_lst[3]),
    ])

print(df)
```

This gives the working output:

```
          Task       Start         End
0  DateRange 1  2020-01-01  2021-01-01
1  DateRange 2  2022-01-01  2023-01-01
```

However, if the condition is not met, e.g. if `start_date` is changed to `datetime.date(2025, 1, 1)`, the final list has only two entries. Index [2] and [3] cannot be called and it returns the error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Is there a way to avoid this outcome while still visualizing all dates available? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now solved this issue using a function to check if the index exists, otherwise replacing it with an empty string. Full code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# Function to check if index exists
def check_index(lst, index):
    if index < len(lst):
        return lst[index]
    else:
        lst.insert(index, "")
        return lst[index]


start_date = datetime.date(2025, 1, 1)

date_lst = [datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), datetime.date(2021, 1, 1)]
condition = 0


if date_lst[0] > start_date:
    date_lst.append(datetime.date(2022, 1, 1))
    date_lst.append(datetime.date(2023, 1, 1))
else:
    pass

df = pd.DataFrame([
        dict(Task="DateRange 1", Start=check_index(date_lst, 0), End=check_index(date_lst, 1)),
        dict(Task="DateRange 2", Start=check_index(date_lst, 2), End=check_index(date_lst, 3)),
    ])

print(df)
```

Output:

```py
          Task       Start         End
0  DateRange 1  2020-01-01  2021-01-01
1  DateRange 2
```

This solution seems somewhat convoluted; I will gladly accept a better approach as answer.